# Link to Anchor tag with .net dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, .net

im working on a website thats built using .net.

Theres a dropdown on my page that when an option is selected ther page refreshes, what I need though is for the page to refresh and link to an anchor further down my page "#company-detail"

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Companies" runat="server" CssClass="selectd" onselectedindexchanged="DDL_Companies_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Select a partner...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>opt</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>opt</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>opt</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>opt</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>opt</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with javascript instead of roundtrip to the server.
remove the AutoPostBack=true then add an onchange() event to the rendered select element. Do your navigation to the url there

EDIT:
Sorry, didn't see your requirement for the page to refresh. I guess you can, on the roundtrip to the server, add a RegisterClientScriptBlock so that the navigation the page section happens on the client side after the refresh. This will preserve the values on the page, instead of a response.redirect server side
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can reload page when select an item like this: `Response.Redirect("yourHost.aspx#company-detail")`

Comment: Set Dropdown event: `protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something and then
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath+"#company-detail");
        }` But if you do it you will lose the information that you gather before (View State). Instead you can use Jquery look at this example: `$('#myDropdownId').change(function(){
 window.location.hash = 'live';
});`